# How to make sure threads are being fully executed? (using thread pool)

Tags: java, arrays, threadpool

My assignment is to create a program in which 3 coordinators add 200 students to 1 course. I am using a thread pool and in the end printing the Array of student numbers which were enrolled to the course.

For some reason - in most cases when I run the java main program it really does add 200 students to the array --- but! every now and then it assigns less, and tells me the array size is 160, 170... Please, if you can see what's causing this I would love some help.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ClassMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 200 ;i++) {
            Runnable coordinator = new Coordinator(i);
            executor.execute(coordinator);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while (!executor.isTerminated());

        Coordinator.print();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Coordinator implements Runnable
{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> javaStudents;

    private int studentNumber;

    public Coordinator(int studentNum)
    {
        studentNumber = studentNum;
        javaStudents = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public static synchronized void processCommand(int studentNumber)
    {
        javaStudents.add(studentNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Starting to add student# " + studentNumber + " to Java");
        processCommand(studentNumber);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Ended adding student#" + studentNumber + " to Java");
    }

    public static void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < javaStudents.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Student #" +javaStudents.get(i) + " enrolled to Java");
        }
        System.out.println("Array size: " + javaStudents.size());
    }
}
```

I expect the Array size to always be 200, but in some runs it varies...

Comment: You are mixing and matching `static` and instance fields.

Comment: Use `ExecutorService.awaitShutdown()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your `Coordinator` constructor is the problem:

```
javaStudents = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

You are overwriting the `static` `javaStudents` field each time a `Coordinator` is constructed. Remove this line, and change your `static` field declaration to:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> javaStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: could not thank you enough for this! :) solved the problem